# Is libQtDeclarative required for QML?

Tags: qt, qt4, qml, qtdeclarative

I'm not sure if libQtDeclarative.a is required for QML. Is it? If not, what is it for exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is. From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qmlruntime.html):

> QML documents are loaded and executed by the QML runtime. This includes the Declarative UI engine along with the built-in QML elements and plugin modules, and it also provides access to third-party QML elements and modules.
>
> Applications that use QML need to invoke the QML runtime in order to execute QML documents. This can be done by creating a QDeclarativeView or a QDeclarativeEngine, as described below. In addition, the Declarative UI package includes the Qt QML Viewer tool, which loads .qml files. This tool is useful for developing and testing QML code without the need to write a C++ application to load the QML runtime.

On my Qt build (Windows), using Dependency Walker, you can see that `QDeclarativeView` and `QDeclarativeEngine` (and others) are defined in this library.

More information about this module can be found [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qtdeclarative.html).